# Mongoose model.proptype.save error with passport.js

Tags: mongoose, passport.js

I use `passport.js` and `passport-local-mongoose` for user authenction. User register goes well. But user login dont work. Terminal show me this error: `MongooseError Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback`

This my code. But i cant found any error help me please:

```
router.get('/login_success', (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).json(
        req.user
    );
});

router.get('/login_error', (req, res) => {
    return res.status(401).json({message:"Ýalnyş maglumat"})    
});

router.post("/login", 
    passport.authenticate("local", { successRedirect: '/api/auth/login_success', failureRedirect: '/api/auth/login_error' }
) , function (req, res) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found problem. Problem with new version `mongoose^7.0.0`. After installed `mongoose^6.9.0` work well